# C# How to parse text file by grouping?

Tags: c#, parsing, text

I have a simple program which reads a log text file and tries to parse it.

The program would be ablle to "group"/parse the log text file by "----------------------" which I have tried to use the ".split" method but it does not work.

Basically if possible I would like the program to group the text file between from each "----------------" to "---------------" for other processes.

Can someone please advise on the codes? Thanks!

My codes:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<String> lines = File.ReadLines("C:\\Syscrawl\\new.txt");

        foreach (String r in lines.Skip(7))
        {

            String[] token = r.Split('-');

            foreach (String t in token)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A Sample pf the Text File;

```
Restore Point Info
Description   : Installed Apache HTTP Server 2.2.16
Type          : Application Install
Creation Time : Thu Dec  9 08:04:46 2010

C:\syscrawl\Restore\RP10\snapshot\_REGISTRY_USER_NTUSER_S-
1-5-21-1390067357-413027322-1801674531-500

Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RecentDocs not found.
----------------------------------------
Restore Point Info
Description   : Testing 0
Type          : System CheckPoint
Creation Time : Thu Dec  9 08:05:43 2010

C:\syscrawl\Restore\RP11\snapshot\_REGISTRY_USER_NTUSER_S-
1-5-21-1390067357-413027322-1801674531-500

Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RecentDocs not found.
----------------------------------------
Restore Point Info
Description   : Installed Python 2.4.1
Type          : Application Install
Creation Time : Thu Dec  9 08:09:12 2010

C:\syscrawl\Restore\RP12\snapshot\_REGISTRY_USER_NTUSER_S-
1-5-21-1390067357-413027322-1801674531-500

Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RecentDocs not found.
----------------------------------------
Restore Point Info
Description   : Installed AccessData FTK Imager.
Type          : Application Install
Creation Time : Thu Dec  9 08:14:02 2010

C:\syscrawl\Restore\RP13\snapshot\_REGISTRY_USER_NTUSER_S-
1-5-21-1390067357-413027322-1801674531-500

Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RecentDocs not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are splitting each line, not the file as a single piece of data.

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Syscrawl\\new.txt");
var logItems = fileContent.Split(new string[]{"----------------------"}, false);
```

Each of these `logItems` will still have its line breaks included when you render it on screen.  I'd keep them as a single piece of data rather than split them into lines.

Comment: Lots of errors generated. The "Split" method cannot take in String as a variable to split but only arrays.

Answer (score 2):

A reasonably simple iterator can give you a sequence of the sets of lines between dividers:

```
static IEnumerable<IList<string>> ParseLines(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    var lineSet = new List<string>();
    foreach(var line in lines)
    {
        if(line.StartsWith("----"))
        {
            yield return lineSet;
            lineSet = new List<string>();
        }
        else
        {
            lineSet.Add(line);
        }
    }
}
```